# b.delegate is not a function exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just use jquery shake effect and that is why i include two jquery file.

here is code which shake a div

```
var isShaking = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (!isShaking) {
            if ($('#<% =EnableCookie.ClientID %>').length > 0) {
                isShaking = true;
                $('#<% =EnableCookie.ClientID %>').effect('shake', 100, function() {
                    isShaking = false;
                });
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

when i am running the apps then shake effect play again & again but firebug gives a error called **b.delegate is not a function** which is not clear to me and also i am not being able to understand where i am making the mistake. so please guide me. thanks

Comment: Which jquery files/versions are you including? It's not simply the jquery library twice, but jquery and a plugin, correct?

Comment: i am using bit old one.jquery-1.4.1.min.js & jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Could you create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incompatible versions of jquery and jqueryui. The `.delegate()` function was only added in jquery 1.4.2. (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/))

The latest jqueryui version requires jquery 1.6+ (see [here](http://jqueryui.com/)).